# Determining Use of Google Maps API Key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to track down the use of all the Google API keys for an account.  There are a few keys which don't have referrer's set and are generically named, but are being used according to the statistics.  Is there anyway to determine the referrer/url that is using an existing API key?

FYI, I do know that the referrer should be set, these are keys that weren't created by me or were created many years ago when I was young and stupid. :-)

Comment: Can somebody explain why this is down-voted?  I genuinely curious so I know for the future.  Should I have asked this somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only current way for you to know the domains of the API Keys that are being used is to:

1. Restrict your API Key. By doing so, the other domains will be unable to use the API Key that is not in the list of referrers. See [API Key Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) or,
2. Start fresh by creating a new Key and properly restrict it with the domains you are aware of. Then start migrating it to the sites that you built. Then eventually, delete the old key at least until June 11, as that will be the date when the changes will be implemented.

You can also contact Google Cloud Support but you will receive the same answer, as they will not give you the domains if your API Key is unrestricted. Here are also some of the best practices for you:

1. You can set [Budgets Alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) which will notify you if you reach the conditions you set. You can cap your usage by setting consumer quota limits on a per-API basis from the Cloud Console.
2. I also encourage you to follow the [API key best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) and,
3. Use these strategies detailed on the [Optimization Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide)